# URLClassLoader NoClassDefFound Exception when loading class from JAR

Tags: java, scala, plugins, noclassdeffounderror, urlclassloader

I am trying to write my own small plugin loader:

```
package some.package.plugins

import org.clapper.classutil.{ClassFinder, ClassInfo}
import wvlet.log.LogSupport
import java.io.File
import java.net.{URL, URLClassLoader}

object PluginManager extends LogSupport {

  val PLUGIN_DIRECTOR = "./plugins/"
  val PLUGIN_INTERFACE = "package.Plugin"

  val jars: List[File] = new File(PLUGIN_DIRECTOR).listFiles.filter(_.getPath.endsWith(".jar")).toList
  private val pluginMap : Map[String,(ClassInfo,File)] = {
    jars.flatMap {
      jar =>
        val finder = ClassFinder(List(jar))
        println(finder.getClasses().map(_.interfaces).toList)
        finder.getClasses().filter(_.interfaces.contains(PLUGIN_INTERFACE)).map {
          info =>
            info.name.split("\\.").last -> (info, jar)
        }
    }.toMap
  }

  def getPlugins : Set[String] = pluginMap.keySet

  def loadPlugins(name : String) : AnalysisPlugin = {
    val classInfo : (ClassInfo,File) = pluginMap.getOrElse(name,throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"the plugin $name does not exist"))
    val urls : List[URL] = List(classInfo._2.toURI.toURL)
    val childClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls.toArray, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader)
    info(s"loading plugin ${classInfo._1.name}")
    val c: Class[_] = childClassLoader.loadClass(classInfo._1.name)
    assert(c.getConstructors.length == 1)
    c.getConstructors.head.newInstance().asInstanceOf[AnalysisPlugin]
  }

}
```

I use `ClassFinder` and `ClassInfo` to identify all classes in a `.jar` that implement the `PLUGIN_INTERFACE`.
The output confirms that I do find the class that does. I then use the `URLClassLoader` provided with exactly the same jars to load the corresponding class using `childClassLoader.loadClass` but I get a `NoClassDefFound` exception.

The issue here seems to be the interface class, i.e., die interface that is supposed to enable different plugins being transparent for the plugin manager. `package.Plugin` is the class that cannot be loaded.

How can I load a class contained in a `.jar` using `URLClassLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the underlying logic but you need to provide a different parent class loader to the `URLClassLoader`. After some fuzzing I successfully ran the code using the class loader of the object containing the main function:

```
  def loadPlugins(name : String) : Option[AnalysisPlugin] = {
    val classInfo: (ClassInfo, File) = pluginMap.getOrElse(name, throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"the plugin $name does not exist"))
    val urls: List[URL] = List(classInfo._2.toURI.toURL)
    val parentClassLoader = Main.getClass.getClassLoader
    val childClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls.toArray, parentClassLoader)
    try {
      info(s"loading plugin ${classInfo._1.name}")
      Some(Class.forName(classInfo._1.name,true, childClassLoader).newInstance().asInstanceOf[AnalysisPlugin])
    } catch {
      case x : NoClassDefFoundError =>
        error(x)
        error(s"plugin $name cannot be loaded check the plugin directory and make sure it is contained")
        None
    } finally {
      childClassLoader.close()
    }
  }
```